# Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I have created custom shipping module and gets following error:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function setStore() on a non-object in **/home/devjoand/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping.php** on line **421**

I removed all files including .xml for this shipping module and it still gives me the same error. It doesn't send me to shipping method and stops execution from savebilling controller with above error. I have cleared cache/session and recompile but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

NOTE: It works fine in my local machine but not working on production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you remove the files there are still the config settings that remain the `core_config_data` table.
When checking the available shipping methods magento looks for the values from the config on this path `carriers/{carrier_code_here}/active`. Then for all carrier codes that the value on the path mentioned above is 1 it tries to load the shipping method model.
If you deleted the files it does not exist anymore.
So make sure you delete the values from the `core_config_data` `where path like 'carriers/{carrier_code_here}/%'`